# Rails 3 Render In Rescue Block

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, transactions

I'm creating a series of objects on the fly using transaction and exception handling. Right now it handles the rollback and everything as expected but my rescue block doesn't attempt to render the action I tell it to.

Here's my code that handles the transaction

```
def post_validation
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    begin
      params[:users].each do |user|
          #process each user and save here   
      end 
      redirect_to root_path #success
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      # something went wrong, roll back          
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback 
      flash[:error] = "Please resolve any validation errors and re-submit"          
      render :action => "validation"          
    end
  end    
end
```

**What's expected upon failure:** Rolls back transaction and renders the action "validation".

**What's happening upon failure:** Rolls back transaction and attempts to render the view "post_validation" which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it looks like there's a few things wrong with the code I provided. For starters you don't need to bother with the `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` line, Rails does this behind the scenes when an exception is thrown inside of a transaction block. In addition the transaction block needed to be inside of the begin block. So the resulting code looked something like this:

```
def post_validation
  begin      
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      #process some new records here
      redirect_to root_path 
    end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    # handle the exception here; the entire transaction gets rolled-back        
    flash[:error] = "Please resolve any validation errors and re-submit"          
    render :action => "validation"          
  end
end
```